# detect the whether device has turned off the touch id feature

Tags: android, react-native, touch-id

How can i detect, whether the user has turned off the touch id, from the phone for unlocking the phone, however has the fingerprints enrolled in react-native.

I am using the **react-native-touchid** library which provides, **isSupported** and **authenticate** function (which also *catches the error*), but it returns true when we have turned off the touch id.